# Do the Amazon SDK for iOS / Swift sample code examples work for Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

The sample code is for an earlier version of Swift and includes deprecated iOS functionality. But when converted and built it doesn't appear to work.  Has anyone managed to get these examples working and if so what did it take?

Comment: Update: I posted on the Github 'Issues' thread on this point and got the following reply. "The code sample is currently not compatible with Xcode 7/Swift 2. When we update the samples, we'll update the thread. Thanks." Right now no indication of when the samples will be updated.

Comment: They have updated the github repo and it now works for XCode7 and Swift 2.0.